# Connecting multiple .ui files in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a window(.ui file) and at certain point i want to erase everything inside of it and repaint a new interface by connecting a new .ui file to that class without creating seperate class. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Can't you use the [`visible` property of `QWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#visible-prop) to hide/show the different parts?

Comment: I might need to place the new widgets on the same place where the previous ones used to be.

Comment: If you put them in a `QVBoxLayout` and you make only one visible at each moment, they will occupy the same place.

Comment: Would I be able then to place them in designer mode?

Comment: You can indeed add both `QWidget`s in the designer and hide one of them. Is it necessary for you to use two .ui files?

Comment: Have you thought of using a QStackedWidget: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QStackedWidget.html. Sounds like what you are looking for and you can style all pages conveniently in the designer.

Comment: Thank you, StackedWidget is what I was looking for

Comment: @Lorenz Can you convert your comment into an answer, so the OP can accept it and other people can find the solution more easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The task sounds like a good job for [`QStackedWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QStackedWidget.html). With its help you can design different widgets (aka "pages") conveniently in the designer, and switch between them inside your code using `setCurrentIndex()` and/or `setCurrentPage()`.