# How to create Multiple frames on a single Window in Qt Designer

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I am new to Qt and just jumped from Tkinter to Qt Designer to make GUI Easy application.

Using Qt Designer I am able to generate seperate .ui files for all windows, 
Where as in Tkinter I had an option to create Frames and Stack one on another , and show only Active Frame.

I need to create a Main page with two buttons Login and Signup 
if I click Login , the window should load within the container but not as a new window, how do I achieve this using QT Designer ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting multiple .ui files in Qt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43684439/connecting-multiple-ui-files-in-qt)